# Globe SSL with NGINX SSL certificate issue

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, openssl

I have a big problem with installing a certificat for nginx (same happends with apache though)
I have 3 files  __domain_com.crt __domain_com.ca-bundle and ssl.key.
I tried to append cat __domain_com.crt __leechpack_com.ca-bundle > bundle.crt but if I do it like this i get an error:

```
[emerg]: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file("/etc/nginx/__leechpack_com.crt") failed (SSL: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib)
```

And that's because the delimiters of the certificates arren't separated.

```
ZqTjb+WBJQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE----------BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE6DCCA9CgAwIBAgIQdIYhlpUQySkmKUvMi/gpLDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBv
```

If I separate them with an enter between certificated it will at least start but I will get the same warning from Firefox:

```
This Connection is Untrusted
You have asked Firefox to connect
securely to domain.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.
```

The concatenate solution it is given by Globe SSL and the NGINX site but it doesn't work.
I think the bundle is ignored though.

- http://customer.globessl.com/knowledgebase/55/Certificate-Installation--Nginx.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains
- http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpSslModule

If I do `openssl s_client -connect down.leechpack.com:443`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Provided by Globe Hosting, Inc./OU=Globe Standard Wildcard SSL/CN=*.domain.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Provided by Globe Hosting, Inc./OU=Globe Standard Wildcard SSL/CN=*.domain.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Provided by Globe Hosting, Inc./OU=Globe Standard Wildcard SSL/CN=*.domain.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Provided by Globe Hosting, Inc./OU=Globe Standard Wildcard SSL/CN=*.domain.com
   i:/C=RO/O=GLOBE HOSTING CERTIFICATION AUTHORITY/CN=GLOBE SSL Domain Validated CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=Globe Hosting, Inc./OU=GlobeSSL DV Certification Authority/CN=GlobeSSL CA
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Provided by Globe Hosting, Inc./OU=Globe Standard Wildcard SSL/CN=*.domain.com
issuer=/C=RO/O=GLOBE HOSTING CERTIFICATION AUTHORITY/CN=GLOBE SSL Domain Validated CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3313 bytes and written 343 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 5F9C8DC277A372E28A4684BAE5B311533AD30E251369D144A13DECA3078E067F
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 9B531A75347E6E7D19D95365C1208F2ED37E4004AA8F71FC614A18937BEE2ED9F82D58925E0B3931492AD3D2AA6EFD3B
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1288618211
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
```

Answer (score 1):

cat __domain_com.ca-bundle >> __domain_com.crt
In nginx you need use only two files KEY and CRT, and you must merger CRT and CA BUNDLE into one file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you sorted it out, based on connecting to www.leechpack.com. However, the third certificate on that site is the root certificate (which should be omitted).

You're also referencing a lot of resources from http://a.vimeocdn.com/. You should use a scheme-relative url (i.e. //a.vimeocdn.com) so that it doesn't trigger mixed content issues.